# Command line option to run program under gdb after it loads?

Tags: gdb

Whe loading a program with gdb, how do you have gdb automatically start the program and run it without waiting?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [-ex command line option](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/File-Options.html) and provide the run command.

```
gdb -ex=r --args executable --with-options-for-the-executable
```